# Special characters(&lt; for < and &gt; for >) are saved in sql server 2008

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not able to store the xml element chars('<' and '>') in SQL server 2008 R2.

If I am trying to insert Name as (XYZ) from a java code(Hibernate ORM) persisting the value in SQL server, the value is getting stored as the database.:

```
&lt;value&gt;XYZ&lt;/value&gt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to store the unescaped value('<' and '>'). My code was written to escape the XML elements with the following utillity`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(String)`